# Regex not applying my non capturing positive lookahead at the right position?

Tags: regex

I have the line...

```
[2] = "2012-06-25 00:00:44 W3SVC1768084652 22.66.33.11 GET /errorpage/404.aspx/ 404;http://www.mydomain.com:8050/images/bg_vertical_menu_arrow.gif 8050 - 10.22.77.11 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/4.0;+GTB7.3;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.5...
```

And the regular expression...

```
(http://.*)(?=\s)
```

But I get:

```
http://www.mydomain.com:8050/images/bg_vertical_menu_arrow.gif 8050 - 10.22.77.11
```

As the match, which is annoying because there is clearly a whitespace after the .gif part and this is where the regex should stop no?

Comment: `(http://[^ ]+)` = match until white space, your regex is greedy and matches right to the end (`.*`) and then backtracks until a whitespace is found (from the right!).

Answer (score 1):

How about this :

```
http[a-z://0-9\.\?_=\&]*
```

Tested at http://regexr.com?31cgt

Comment: This (`http[a-z://0-9\.\?_=\&]*
`) looks not very good for my taste. `a-z0-9_`is can be shortended to `\w` and additionally includes `U`ppercase then. `\&\?\.`are *no special chars* in character class, so they need *not* to be escaped. In a character class, `//` is the same as `/`.

Comment: @rubber boots this will work for 192.168.1.100 ip adresses as well as for his example and some others including url params etc. If you're talking just about his example you're absolutely right. This is what I use as general to capture full urls

Comment: OK, but what about `UPPERCASE` letters in urls? Why would a simple `http[\S]+` (or simply `http\S+`) not suffice?

Comment: @rubber boots it would suffice but I don't see this question being tagged java regex. As for uppercase you probably know just add A-Z in the []

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your regex by `(http:\/\/.*?)(?=\s)` or use the simply one `(http:\/\/\S*)`.